# Want material to teach Unix basics

Tags: shell-script

HP-UX ** B.11.31 U ia64 ** unlimited-user license
Hi,
I have been working as a script (korn and bash)developer on Unix platforms for 3+ years. I have to train a team on Unix. And although I know a few things, I just am not able to gather these concepts and deliver one after other. I end up finding all concepts inter-related and just dont know where(what topic/subtopic) to start, and hence find it very very hard to convey what I really know.

So far, two sessions have been given, first session, basic Unix commands which include mkdir,cd,ls,more,hostname,head tail,cat,find,apropos,man,etc/passwd, uname etc..

The second session, since I thought vi is very important I gave a discourse on vi editor. Everything related to vi.

But these days since you have EOL conversions on sophisticated editors that have ftp and sftp, (which I also have demo-ed to this team), you dont really need vi.

Hence please post some concise material that I can teach, anything, blogpost, ppt, chapter in a book,etc. I am really looking for some material that is concise and useful(to use and to teach) for permissions on Unix. The session can last for two to three hours. This is not a question like "what is the best IDE for Java" or "best book for Java" hence please do not close it.

Comment: I think this question is going to be closed, sorry. But you could hop into the chat room, and probably people will be willing to offer suggestions. Why not take a look at some basic Unix books or tutorials on the web to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this information is dated, I've always enjoyed learning from those that developed Unix- http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/bswv7.html